# Check multiple `keys` in Python dictionary

Tags: python

`my_dict = {'a': 'Devashish'}`

For example, if I do like: `my_dict.get('A', None)  #None`

How to do like: `my_dict.get('A', 'a', None)  #'Devashish'`

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is check from `1st` condition to `n-1` and return the result when Key is matching otherwise return the last value.

Comment: You'd have to write that yourself, there's nothing built in. You'd probably be better canonicalising the key, in this case always using lowercase *or* uppercase.

Comment: What have you tried? a simple for loop iterating over possible keys solves your problem..

Comment: you could do smth like `my_dict.get('A', my_dict.get('a', None))` - but its better to use lowercase keys - tagging this _double.get_ around all the time gets ugly fast. Better wrap your dict in some class that manages key-casing.

Comment: Basically, a general scenario for me is I need to check either `userPrincipalName` or `UserPrincipalName` is in the `dict` or just return `None`. So I think @PatrickArtner's answer will work for me. I just have used `a` and `A` to make it simple to understand the question @RafaelC. Thanks a all of you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the following function should satisfy your specs.

```
>>> def get_first(dict_, keys,  default):
...     for k in keys:
...         try:
...             return dict_[k]
...         except KeyError:
...             pass
...     return default
... 
>>> get_first(d, [-1, 0, 3, 6], 'default')
4
>>> get_first(d, [-1, 0], 'default')
'default'
```

For fun, a recursive variant...

```
>>> def get_first(dict_, keys, default):
...     keys = iter(keys)
...     try:
...         k = next(keys)
...     except StopIteration:
...         return default
...     return dict_.get(k, get_first(dict_, keys, default))

>>> d = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
>>> get_first(d, [-1, 0, 3, 6], 'default')
4
>>> get_first(d, [-1, 0], 'default')
'default'
```

Alternatively, we can do it shorter via calling `next` on a genexp. Hashes the existing key twice, though.

```
>>> next((d[k] for k in [-1, 0, 3, 6] if k in d), 'default')
4
>>> next((d[k] for k in [-1, 0] if k in d), 'default')
'default'
```